# Can I use Evernote API in a server rather than an iOS/Android device

Tags: evernote

Thank you for reading my question a lot. What I want is to create/read a note of Evernote via a server(maybe a web service or not) -- Is it doable? I do not find a J2EE API set of Evernote so far. I really appreciate your comments :-)

Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Of course it's doable.

Take a look at https://dev.evernote.com/doc/#reference for the documentation and https://github.com/evernote/evernote-sdk-java for the java sdk

It's not a REST api though so you'll need to take some time to actually read the documentation.

Have fun !

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm going through the documents :-)